# Annotation for Objectifyfilter

Tags: java, google-app-engine, annotations, objectify

Hi I am using annotation to map the servlet instead of `web.xml`, I am trying to retrive the entities from the datastore using objectify, (I am using java8 version of google app engine) and I am using static block to register the entity(class).

> I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have not started an Objectify context. You are probably missing the ObjectifyFilter. If you are not running in the context of an http request, see the ObjectifyService.run() method.
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy(ObjectifyService.java:44)
```

I know that, need have to objectify filter in the web.xml:(as below code) in my case I am not using web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

> Question:

How can I do this objectify filter in the annotation?

Answer (score 1):

This would require a code change to ObjectifyFilter so it gets a @WebFilter annotation. While you are using annotations for your own Servlet/related code, you could still create a web.xml to define the Objectify filter, which should resolve the issue.

Comment: After specifying objectify filter in ` web.xml` (below code)  `<web-app>

     <filter>
         <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
         <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
     </filter>
     <filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>

 </web-app>`  I can't able to open index page( I am getting `Error 404` errror) @Sai Pullabhotla

Comment: `Error`-com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /index

Comment: Possible misconfiguration with welcome-file-list? Was it working before you added the web.xml? Is there a resource "/index" available in webapp?

Comment: Yes, I am having "index.html" under `WEB-INF`. The branch structure is `/webapp/WEB-INF/(appengine-web.xml, index.html, web.xml)`. I am using servlet to display "index.html" and I don't have any code other than `objectify filter` in `web.xml` because I am using annotation. Yes, its working if I am not having the `web.xml` file other than the objectify servlet( I am getting the `error` shown above) @Sai Pullabhotla

Comment: Not clear on what "/index" is/mapped to. What URL are you accessing to invoke your Servlet? Perhaps edit your question to provide additional details that may help.

Comment: I am using annotation,(1) first  request `http://localhost:8888/index` from the client, (2) web server will use `@WebServlet(value = "/index/*")` to invoke that servlet. (3) In that servlet, I will check whether session is available or not, (4) if there is session available I will forward `index.html` page, (5) else I will send the `login.html` page. but when I use `web.xml` (only Objectify filter) I am getting Error 404 with the error message in the IDE as (`com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /index`) @Sai Pullabhotla

Comment: Question is how to mention objectify filter using annotation, I am using annotation to map the servlet, if I use web.xml to mention the objectify filter and getting `Error 404`, @Sai Pullabhotla

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by creating a class which extends the ObjectifyFilter

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class ObjectifyFilterServlet extends ObjectifyFilter {
}
```

so, Its working fine, but when I use web.xml, for the code

```
<filter>
<filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I am getting `Error 404` for the first request. so I created a simple class which extends ObjectifyFilter, I solved this problem. if there is other solution, share those information also. Thank you